# Problem with generating random string and save into user meta field in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, random

The code must create a random string of numbers and letters and add this as meta field of wordpress user.
This code cause the User Add section to output errors like:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught `ArgumentCountError`: Too few arguments to function `myplugin_registration_save()`, 
1 passed in <path>/class-wp-hook.php on line 286 and exactly 2 expected in <path>/functions.php:347 
Stack trace: 
    #0 <path>/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): myplugin_registration_save(51) 
    #1 <path>/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) 
    #2 <path>/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) 
    #3 <path>/user.php(1857): do_action('user_register', 51) 
    #4 <path>/user.php(226): wp_insert_user(Array) 
    #5 <path>/user-new.php(148): edit_user() 
    #6 {main} thrown in <path>/functions.php on line 347
```

The code:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 30) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

add_action('user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );
function myplugin_registration_save($user_id , $length) {
    $meta_key = "pkg_autologin_code";
    $timestampz=time();
    $tokenparta = generateRandomString();
    $key = $timestampz*3 . $tokenparta;
    update_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key , $key);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the documentation for the [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) function, you'll see the fourth argument is `int $accepted_args`.

You have to change the `1` to a `2` on your `add_action()` call. So change this line:

```
add_action('user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );
```

to

```
add_action('user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks.
In origin it was add_action('user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 2 ); but it doesn't work so i've tried with 1.
in any case generates Fatal Error.

Answer (score 0):

i've edited removing the $lenght from function line:

```
   function generateRandomString($length = 30) {
          $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
          $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
          $randomString = '';
          for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
          $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
          }
   return $randomString;
   }
   add_action('user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 2);
   function myplugin_registration_save($user_id) {
          $meta_key = "pkg_autologin_code";
          $timestampz=time();
          $tokenparta = generateRandomString();
          $key = $timestampz*3 . $tokenparta;
          update_user_meta($user_id, "pkg_autologin_code", $key);
   }
```

It seems to work.